# Como Retirar Informação De Consulta SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, query, select

Ao aplicar o `select` ele puxa data e horas, porém só quero que resulte a data, como faço?

```
SELECT DATAADMISSAO FROM PFUNC
```

Exemplo resultado: `1986-09-17 00:00:00.000`.

Preciso que resulte apenas como: `17/09/1986`.

Comment: Já tentou `DATE(DATAADMISSAO)`?

Comment: eu to pegando SQL agora, então to apanhando bastante, como ficaria o SELECT nesse caso?

Comment: tava vendo aqui sobre o DATEFROMPARTS, porém como quero buscar toda a tabela DATAADMISSAO, não to conseguindo acertar na query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo retorno mostrado, o campo `DATAADMISSAO` já é do tipo data; então basta que você formate o retorno, por exemplo com o método [`FORMAT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15)

```
SELECT FORMAT (DATAADMISSAO, 'dd/MM/yyyy') FROM PFUNC
```

Também é possível fazer isso usando o [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATAADMISSAO, 103) FROM PFUNC
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! deu certo...